# Jhipster yo jhipster is not updating existing project

Tags: jhipster

I have created a project using Jhipster v4.0.5. Now have upgraded **generator-jhipster** to latest one i.e. v4.0.7 and tried to upgrade my existing project manually. But upgrade is not happening because no single file is changed after using command **yo jhipster** or **yo jhipster --with-entities**.
Have confirmed this through '.yo-rc.json', it is still showing **{"jhipsterVersion": "4.0.5"}**.

Does anyone know fix for this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using the generator-jhipster in your project's `node_modules` folder, delete it and re-run `npm install` or `yarn install`.

Why don't you use `yo jhipster:upgrade` rather than re-generating everything and losing all your customizations? See [documentation](http://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/)

Comment: Thanks man, I removed local generator-jhipster and it worked. For future will use jhipster sub generator yo jhipster:upgrade to upgrade application.

Comment: Accepted your answer.