# Upgrading jhipster version on old project

Tags: git, upgrade, jhipster

I have an old jhipster project that was generated using version 3.9.1 (originally), after having to work on it again the first thing I want is to upgrade jhipster to the latest version since there has been a lot of improvements.

I cloned the repo, installed everything necessary and tried to run the project. Everything worked ! so then I run `yo jhipster:upgrade` on the root folder of the project. After some permission problems and a few missing packages it finally did the upgrade but to version 3.12.2 instead of 4.6.1 (latest).

At this point I had to solve a few conflicts to get the project running again, no problem. I checked it and the version of my package "generator-jhipster" is indeed 4.6.1 (latest).

I've tried running the upgrade process a few times, even forcing the version with `--target-version=4.6.1` but after the upgrade seemingly goes well the project is still running on jhipster 3.12.2.

I tried the solution here [Jhipster yo jhipster is not updating existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556955/jhipster-yo-jhipster-is-not-updating-existing-project) with no luck.

What am I doing wrong? or what are the steps to successfully upgrade? The upgrade page on jhipster's website is very vague...

Here is a typical upgrade log:

```
   Welcome to the JHipster Upgrade Sub-Generator
    This will upgrade your current application codebase to the latest JHipster version
    Looking for latest generator-jhipster version...
    New generator-jhipster version found: 4.6.1
    Git repository detected
    Updating generator-jhipster. This might take some time...
    Updated generator-jhipster to version 4.6.1
    Checked out branch "jhipster_upgrade"
    Cleaned up directory
    Regenerating app with jhipster 4.6.1...

            ██  ██    ██  ████████  ███████    ██████  ████████  ████████  ███████
            ██  ██    ██     ██     ██    ██  ██          ██     ██        ██    ██
            ██  ████████     ██     ███████    █████      ██     ██████    ███████
      ██    ██  ██    ██     ██     ██             ██     ██     ██        ██   ██
       ██████   ██    ██  ████████  ██        ██████      ██     ████████  ██    ██

                                http://jhipster.github.io

    Welcome to the JHipster Generator v3.12.2
    Documentation for creating an application: https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-app/
    Application files will be generated in folder: C:\Users\quosei\Documents\GitHub\Agora
     ______________________________________________________________________________

      JHipster update available: 4.6.1 (current: 3.12.2)
      Run npm install -g generator-jhipster to update.
     ______________________________________________________________________________

    This is an existing project, using the configuration from your .yo-rc.json file
    to re-generate the project...

    [A LOT OF FILE CHANGES (SKIPPED FOR READABILITY)]

    Successfully regenerated app with jhipster 4.6.1
    Committed with message "Generated with JHipster 4.6.1"
    Checked out branch "master"
    Merging changes back to master...
    Merge done!

    I'm all done. Running npm install && bower install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.

    [NPM INSTALL && BOWER INSTALL RUN WITHOUT PROBLEM (SKIPPED FOR READABILITY)]

    > yodoctor


    Yeoman Doctor
    Running sanity checks on your system

    √ Global configuration file is valid
    √ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
    √ Node.js version
    √ No .bowerrc file in home directory
    √ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
    √ npm version

    Everything looks all right!

    > optipng-bin@3.1.4 postinstall C:\Users\quosei\Documents\GitHub\Agora\node_modules\optipng-bin
    > node lib/install.js

      √ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

    > jpegtran-bin@3.2.0 postinstall C:\Users\quosei\Documents\GitHub\Agora\node_modules\jpegtran-bin
    > node lib/install.js

      √ jpegtran pre-build test passed successfully

    > gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall C:\Users\quosei\Documents\GitHub\Agora\node_modules\gifsicle
    > node lib/install.js

      √ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully

    > spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall C:\Users\quosei\Documents\GitHub\Agora\node_modules\spawn-sync
    > node postinstall

    added 1485 packages in 101.329s
    [09:45:32] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\GitHub\Agora\gulpfile.js
    [09:45:32] Starting 'install'...
    [09:45:32] Starting 'inject:test'...
    [09:45:33] Starting 'inject:vendor'...
    [09:45:33] Starting 'ngconstant:dev'...
    [09:45:33] Finished 'install' after 177 ms
    [09:45:33] Finished 'ngconstant:dev' after 122 ms
    [09:45:33] gulp-inject 33 files into karma.conf.js.
    [09:45:33] gulp-inject 36 files into index.html.
    [09:45:33] Finished 'inject:test' after 261 ms
    [09:45:33] Finished 'inject:vendor' after 202 ms
    [09:45:33] Starting 'inject:dep'...
    [09:45:33] Finished 'inject:dep' after 6.74 μs
    [09:45:33] Starting 'copy:languages'...
    [09:45:33] Finished 'copy:languages' after 9.7 ms
    [09:45:33] Starting 'inject:app'...
    [09:45:33] gulp-inject 205 files into index.html.
    [09:45:33] Finished 'inject:app' after 319 ms
    [09:45:33] Starting 'inject:troubleshoot'...
    [09:45:33] gulp-inject Nothing to inject into index.html.
    [09:45:33] Finished 'inject:troubleshoot' after 12 ms

    Upgraded successfully. Please now fix conflicts if any, and commit!
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Check the commits in `jhipster_upgrade`, see what has been done in the commit *Generated with JHipster 3.12.2*.

Comment: The branch `jhipster_upgrade` does not exist anymore. I see some commits titled _Generated with JHipster 4.6.1_ with many changes followed by a merge into the master branch. Thank you :)

Comment: Consult https://jhipster.github.io/upgrading-an-application/ for the detailed upgrade procedure, I suffered from similiar issue prior to JHipster 4.5.6, because of both commits in the branch was generated by *exact* the same version of JHipster, and generate no difference to merge into `master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### JHipster upgrade issue

if does not works

`yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster`

then

`yarn global add generator-jhipster
 yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster`

 or

`yo`